# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 251), indices imply (6, 1)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am getting an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

today = date.today()
start = (today.year-1, today.month, today.day)
quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl('AXP', start, today)
fields = ['date', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume']
list1 = []
for i in range(len(quotes)):
    x = date.fromordinal(int(quotes[i][0]))
    y = datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
list1.append(y)
quotesdf = pd.DataFrame(quotes, index = list1, columns = fields)
quotesdf = quotesdf.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
print quotesdf
```

[image]

How can I change my code to achieve my goal, change the dateform and delete the original one?

Comment: `quotesdf = quotesdf.drop(['date'], axis = 1` seems unnecessary. Doesn't `quotesdf.drop(['date'], axis = 1` already store the result in `quotesdf`? And please add more Tags to this question since it's not just a python 2.7 language problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle your code should work, you just need to indent it correctly, that is, you need to append the value of `y` to `list1` **inside** the for loop.

```
for i in range(len(quotes)):
    x = date.fromordinal(int(quotes[i][0]))
    y = datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
    list1.append(y)
```

Thereby `list1` will have as many entries as `quotes` instead of only one (the last one). And the final dataframe will not complain about misshaped data.

Comment: Thank you, I also found this mistake last night.